# How to Convert varchar date type to date format in JPA Criteria Builder?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have a MySQL table(sample_table) in my system for example

| Name | column_value | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 08/24/2020 12:23:10 | -6 |
| BBB | 09/24/2020 12:23:10 | -5 |
| ABC | 10/23/2027 12:23:10 | -3 |
| DBC | 01/08/2016 12:23:10 | -1 |

I want to create a select query in sorted order based on the column_value column.
column_value column is varchar type.
I want to use this query to get the result set.
`select * from sample_table order by str_to_date(column_value, '%m/d%/%Y');`
I am using JPA.

```
TypedQuery<?> buildCriteriaQuery(Class<?> clazz, Class<?> resultClass, String... columnsToSelect) {
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
if (resultClass == null) {
    resultClass = clazz;
}

CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(resultClass);
Root<?> root = criteriaQuery.from(clazz);

## I want to add orderby criteria using criteriaBuilder

Path<Object> columnValue = root.get("columnValue");
javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<String> timeStr = criteriaBuilder.function("STR_TO_DATE", String.class, columnValue, criteriaBuilder.literal("'%m/%d/%Y %r'"));
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(timeStr));
TypedQuery<?> executableQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
return executableQuery;
}
```

But I am getting exception

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "STR_TO_DATE" not found; SQL statement:
> select valfq0_.name as name, valfq0_.COLUMN_VALUE as column_v5_15_, valfq0_.frequency as value_fr6_15_ from order by STR_TO_DATE(valfq0_.COLUMN_VALUE,?) asc limit ? [90022-197]

I wanted to know is there any way to achieve str_to_date conversion in orderby statement.
**Note : ** My JPA query is for MySql db.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting date, time, datetime and timestamp types in the query is bad practice. You should use the supported `java.time.*` types directly or `java.sql.Date`/`java.sql.Time`/`java.sql.Timestamp` types, or `java.util.Date` and setting TemporalType. You're supposed to handle the conversion to the desired client format in your java application.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but this is a special case the column_value actually meant for keeping the value of all datatype, we use it for column profiling stat. that is how it should be. there is a requirement where I need to sort this value column.

Comment: Well the same rule applies. Also you're getting that exception because you're executing it on an H2 database, not MySQL. `str_to_date` is a mysql-specific function.